# plotting effect of the interaction between 2 explanatory variables on the response variable from a generalized linear mixed effect model (glmer) in R

Tags: r, glm, interaction

I have the following code
`glmer(Success ~ Trial*Treatment + 1|ID + Origin + Shelter, family = binomial, data = rama)`

It gives me a significant effect of the interaction between Trial and Treatment on the response variable success.

I would like to plot this interaction.
I tried to use
`plot(Success ~ Trial*Treatment, data = rama)`
But it doesn't plot the interaction, rather makes two different plots, one Success vs Trial and another Success vs Treatment.
Ideally, I would like to merge these two graphs, a bit as what I would get if it was an LME instead of a GLME and I plotted (if success was a continuous variable) and I'd use the following code
`boxplot(Success ~ Trial*Treatment, data = rama)`

I would be super happy if anyone has an idea.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: The `emmeans` package has the `emmip` function to create interaction plots from models.

Comment: the `effects` pkg can probably do this too. If you can come up with a `glm()`-based reproducible example (e.g. with `mtcars`), I bet the same `effects`- or `emmeans`-based machinery will also work with `glmer`

Comment: Thank you very much for your answers! How would you write the code with the emmip function? I can't get my head around it

Comment: as Ben said, if you can make a reproducible example we can illustrate it

Comment: like this for example ?
```M43 <- glmer(am ~ wt*vs+ 1|carb, data = mtcars, family = "binomial")```with mtcars. Looking for the plot of the effect of the interaction between wt and vs on am ?